# Using find() to match multiple conditions

Tags: meteor

I have been using this code to find whether a school exists in a collection or not

```
var sn = 'mit';
var schoolexists = Schools.find({schoolname: sn}, {limit: 1}).count() > 0;
if(schoolexists == true){
    alert('school already exists');
}
```

This works but i now need to introduce two more pointed conditions like `schoollocation`,`studentid` and get only the records that satisfy those three conditions. How would i introduce the two extra conditions?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add them to the selector (the first argument):

```js
var selector = {
  schoolName: 'mit',
  shoolLocation: 'cambridge',
  studentId: 'abc123'
}

var schoolexists = Schools.find(selector, {limit: 1}).count() > 0;
```

Selector fields are **AND**ed together.